# r mice - "sample" imputation method not working correctly

Tags: r, missing-data, r-mice

I am using mice to impute missing data in a large dataset (24k obs, 98 vars). I am using the "sample" imputation method to impute some variables (and other methods for the others - many categorical). When I check my imputed data, those variables that I've applied "sample" to are not always imputed and I have missingness in them. I know for sure that I'm applying "sample" to them (I double checked the methods), and I made sure to remove all predictors of them in the prediction matrix. From my understanding, where they are in the visit sequence shouldn't matter (but I make sure they're immediately after variables with no missingness).

I can't give you a reprex because when I try to recreate the problem, it doesn't happen and everything is imputed just fine. I tried simulating my own data and I tried subsetting the dataset to a group of the variables that I want to use the sample method on. That's part of why I'm so stumped - I coded everything the same and it worked with the subset. I didn't think that the sample method would be at all dependent on the presence of any other vars.

EDIT:
This is the code I'm using

```
#produce prediction matrix 
pred1 <- quickpred_ext(data1, mincor = 0.08, include = "age")
pred2 <- pred1

# for vars to not be imputed, set all predictors to 0
data_no_impute <- data1 %>% 
  select(contains(c("exp_", "outcome_"))) %>% 
  select(sort(names(.))) %>% 
  names

data_level3 <- data1 %>% 
  select(contains(c("f4", "f5", "f6")), 
         k22) %>% 
  select(sort(names(.))) %>% 
  names

pred2[data_no_impute,] <- 0
pred2[data_level3,] <- 0

#produce initial methods and visit sequence
initial <- mice(data1, max = 0, print = F, vis = "monotone", 
                defaultMethod = c("pmm", "logreg", "polyreg", "polr"))

#edit methods to be blank for vars I don't want to impute, "sample" for level 3
meth1 <- initial$meth
meth2 <- meth1
meth2[data_level3] <- "sample"
meth2[data_no_impute] <- ""

visits1 <- initial$visitSequence
visits2 <- visits1
visits2 <- append(visits2, data_level3,22)

#run mice test
mice_test <- mice(data1, m = 2, print = F, 
                  predictorMatrix = pred2,
                  method = meth2,
                  vis = visits2,
                  nnet.MaxNWts = 3000)

#pull second completed dataset
imput1 <- mice::complete(mice_test, 2, include = F)

#look at missingness patterns
missingness_pattern2 <- md.pattern(imput1, plot = F)
```

Comment: If your reprex is working fine, then you need to look at your very large dataset very carefully, but can you describe more about your final product still having missingness in it? Are you saying that there still are `NA` values in your `mids` object?

Comment: I run the following: imput1 <- mice::complete(mice_test, 2, include = F)
missingness_pattern2 <- md.pattern(imput1, plot = F), and get a matrix that reflects missingness corresponding to the vars that should all be complete (assigned "sample" method)

Comment: I'm interested to know why you're using [`action = 2`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/2.46.0/topics/complete) and what you did to get `mice_test`. Can you include your code in your question, even if it isn't a working reprex?